# I need to loop events from the database into a single calendar

Tags: php, jquery

```
<? //Calendar starts ?>     
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'

            },
            editable: true,

      (<? while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_results)){?>),

<? // Events start I need to loop only these events i'm getting from the database table ?>

     events: [
                {
                    id: '',
                    title:  '<?=$row[title];?>',
                    start: '<?=$row[start_time];?>',
                        end: '<?=$row[end_time];?>',

                } ,
            ]
<? // Events ends?>
(<? }?>)

            });


    });
<? //Calendar ends ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `events` be an array? You should also tell us what plugin you're using.

Comment: What's your question about all this code? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you code will create multiple `events` sections, while `events` should be an array so move your loop into the actual `events` section:

```
events: [
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_results)) : ?>
      {
        id: '',
        title: '<?php echo $row[title]; ?>',
        start: '<?php echo $row[start_time]; ?>',
        end: '<?php echo $row[end_time]; ?>',
      },
<?php endwhile; ?>
]
```